# I forgot my password for my password manager (regular ubuntu password manager)

Tags: password-recovery

I forgot my password for my password manager (regular ubuntu password manager) is there any way to find out what the password is?

Comment: If there is, it's a terrible password manager.

Comment: You've not mentioned any Ubuntu product & release details; are we to guess?

Comment: Usually the default initial configuration sets it to your password. If you changed it from there, no way to find out what it is now outside of a serious security hole.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lost the login password for your password manager and the password manager will not allow you to recover it then it will not be possible to do so.

If you are looking for a way to perform a cyber attack on a password manager then I don't think you will find an answer on this forum.